# I don't understand private variables?

Tags: java, private

There is nothing wrong with the code, but I don't understand why you have to create a private String `name`, and then equals that string with the string from method   i.e. `name = n`.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person (String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean sameName(Person other) {
        return getName().equals(getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: `name` is a **member variable** of the class `Person`. See [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: How would you "remember" the name of a person if you don't store it somewhere?

Comment: Are you asking us if you don't understand private variables?

Comment: How would you have done it Ardi? The question sounds like the code you pasted is a bit different than what you have in mind. If the only question is: "why is a variable private" then the answer is described in Jesper's link (the main reason is *encapsulation* - which you can Google)

Comment: Also look into variable scopes. That will explain why you need to assign the arument of the constructor to the member variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A private variable can't be accessed from outside the class, but only by the methods inside the class so it's safer

Comment: So with this line name = n; we brought private variable inside the class ?

Comment: @ArdiMehmeti No, you do that with this line: `private String name;`.

Comment: Private variables like "name" can't be accessed from the other classes. You can't edit the name once you have created a person object but you can only see it by calling the getName() method (in this case), this prevents from setting the internal data of the object into an invalid state. Check out encapsulation.